# Dynamic validation groups in Symfony Forms - via listener or defaultoptions?

Tags: php, facebook, forms, validation, symfony

I have a form which accepts username, password and category_id (and stores it into a Doctrine "User" entity). It creates an account in the database and I am using the validator to have everything checked as required. Now I would like to extend that form so I could support Facebook and Twitter logins (and possibly others) so I have created a new entity UserLoginExternal which will hold a token and a token provider. When the user submits the form for a FB login they submit username, category_id, token and providers. I have created two validation groups in the validator - register and register_without_password but I can't find an efficient way to switch it in the FormType based on whether token field is submitted or not.

Can you point me to the place in the Symfony docs where I can find info about it with an example. I read about the listeners in the form types but I do not have access to the request there to see if token field is submitted.

Comment: How do you distinguish between password and nopassword login? Other websites are showing a link on a login page, that reffers to a alternative login. What about a switch between those 2 different kind of login?

Comment: This is actually an API which serves to authenticate users - so when token is sent to it, it will return an user id, same is with username/password pair. The question is how to switch validation groups on a single form in the FormType so depending on what fields are sent different validation is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to keep one form you have to switch the validation groups based on the submitted data. The Symfony framework offers the functionality for using an callback for that.

You'll find more information about that in the Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data